# Matplotlib plotting- two data sets with different no. of data points

Tags: python, matplotlib, datapoint

I am trying to plot two data sets into the same graph using matplotlib. No. of data points for the first pair of `(x1,y1)` is 150. No. of data points for the second pair `(x2,y2)` is 100. Please note that the range for `x1` and `x2` is from 0.0 to 1.0. Only the no. of data points are different. When I try to plot these into the same graph for comparison,

The error message that appears is:

`"x and y must have same first dimension"`.

Code snippet below for your reference:

```
def main():
    x1,y1 = np.loadtxt('txt1.txt',unpack=True)
    x2,y2 = np.loadtxt('txt2.txt',unpack=True)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x1,y1)
    plt.plot(x2,y2)

main()
```

Comment: your code works for me on two txt files of different length. Try looking at the shape of you `x1, y1, x2` and `y2`. (i.e. `print x1.shape`, etc) to check that the data file have been read correctly

Comment: If that is error you get, it is clear that either `x1 and y1` don't have the same `length`, or `x2 and y2` don't have the same length. As @tom points out, check for the shape of all your four variables. `x1 and y1` and `x2 and y2` should have the same shape.

Comment: @tom thanks for your help. It worked since I mixed up the variable names and hence the shapes of the variables in the actual code.

Comment: As this was effectively a typo - it's probably a good idea to close it down (as it's been solved in comments and won't be of use to others in the future).